# How do I persist data between actions in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just trying to teach myself MVC and I have a problem with the code below,  the _Users list is empty when the Edit action is run, when it was previously populated by Index.  How can I persist this data?  Do I really have to call the service again to get it when I am executing the Edit action?

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public List<User> _Users { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ServiceClient api = new ServiceClient();
        _Users = api.GetUserList();
        return View(_Users);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var user = from u in _Users
                   where u.UserID == id
                   select u;
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since http is stateless, so you have to persist your data somewhere. A local variable won't do. You have to either call the service again or use some other tricks like session, etc.

Comment: OK, so does that mean there is no ViewState in MVC?  I know in Web Forms I would use DataKeys to pull the data back out of a gridview or similar.  Seems a bit wasteful to call a service again, and also it could be quite a lot of data to be going into Session.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ServiceClient` should also provide a method `public User GetUserById(int id)`